# JavaScript remove() only removes item one time

Tags: javascript

I am newer to JavaScript and working on creating a to do list project. I want to use JavaScript to create the elements and style them as opposed to HTML or CSS. I completed the project save one issue, when I set the `remove()` it will only remove an item one time. I can add multiple sections but only delete one. I prefer to build the functions separately and include them into one function if possible.

I have tried using the `remove()`, `removeChild()`, and I'm stuck on why I can only remove an item once. I've looked over my `appendChild()` to make sure everything is connected and it seems to be.

```js
// task list section
const taskBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-blue');
let addTask = document.querySelector('.main-content');
let taskPanel;
let taskPara;
let deletebtn;

//Event Listeners
taskBtn.addEventListener('click', addPanel);

function addPanel(event) {
  //Create div section
  createDiv();
  // Create paragraph
  createPara();
  //create button
  createBtn();
  removeContent();
};

//functions
//Create Div
function createDiv(event) {
  taskPanel = document.createElement('ul');
  taskPanel.setAttribute('class', 'task-added');
  //set css styles
  taskPanel.style.cssText = "display: flex; border: 2px solid #000; border-radius: 5px; margin-top: 2rem; align-items: center; justify-content: space-around; padding-block: 2rem;"
  addTask.appendChild(taskPanel);
}

//Create Paragraph
function createPara(event) {
  taskPara = document.createElement('li');
  taskPara.classList.add('para-1');
  const addInput = document.querySelector('input');
  taskPara.innerText = addInput.value;
  taskPanel.appendChild(taskPara);
}

//Create Button
function createBtn(event) {
  deletebtn = document.createElement('button');
  deletebtn.setAttribute('class', 'btn-icon');
  deletebtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>';
  //set css styles
  deletebtn.style.cssText = "color: red; font-size: 1.5em; border: none; outline: none; padding-inline: 2rem; cursor: pointer;";
  taskPanel.appendChild(deletebtn);
}

function removeContent() {
  deletebtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    taskPanel.remove();
  });
}
```

Comment: You have one `taskPanel` variable, every time you add a new task panel that one variable has its value assigned to the newly created one, so every delete button always acts upon the last task panel created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate the container that holds the button:

```js
function removeContent() {
  deletebtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.target.closest('.task-added').remove();
  });
}
```

### Working example

```js
// task list section
const taskBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-blue');
let addTask = document.querySelector('.main-content');
let taskPanel;
let taskPara;
let deletebtn;

//Event Listeners
taskBtn.addEventListener('click', addPanel);

function addPanel(event) {
  //Create div section
  createDiv();
  // Create paragraph
  createPara();
  //create button
  createBtn();
  removeContent();
};

//functions
//Create Div
function createDiv(event) {
  taskPanel = document.createElement('ul');
  taskPanel.setAttribute('class', 'task-added');
  //set css styles
  taskPanel.style.cssText = "display: flex; border: 2px solid #000; border-radius: 5px; margin-top: 2rem; align-items: center; justify-content: space-around; padding-block: 2rem;"
  addTask.appendChild(taskPanel);
}

//Create Paragraph
function createPara(event) {
  taskPara = document.createElement('li');
  taskPara.classList.add('para-1');
  const addInput = document.querySelector('input');
  taskPara.innerText = addInput.value;
  taskPanel.appendChild(taskPara);
}

//Create Button
function createBtn(event) {
  deletebtn = document.createElement('button');
  deletebtn.setAttribute('class', 'btn-icon');
  deletebtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>';
  //set css styles
  deletebtn.style.cssText = "color: red; font-size: 1.5em; border: none; outline: none; padding-inline: 2rem; cursor: pointer;";
  taskPanel.appendChild(deletebtn);
}

function removeContent() {
  deletebtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.target.closest('.task-added').remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input typ="text" />
<button class="btn-blue">Add Task</button>
<div class="main-content"></div>
```

---

### Avoid globals

Here is a simpler version that doesn't rely on globals.

```js
const addTaskBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-blue');
const taskContainer = document.querySelector('.main-content');

addTaskBtn.addEventListener('click', addPanel);

function addPanel(event) {
  const taskPanel = createTaskPanel();
  taskPanel.append(createTaskDescription());
  taskPanel.append(createTaskDeleteBtn());
  taskContainer.append(taskPanel);
};

function createTaskPanel(event) {
  const taskPanel = document.createElement('div');
  taskPanel.setAttribute('class', 'task-added');
  taskPanel.style.cssText = "display: flex; border: 2px solid #000; border-radius: 5px; margin-top: 2rem; align-items: center; justify-content: space-around; padding-block: 2rem;"
  return taskPanel;
}

function createTaskDescription(event) {
  const taskDescription = document.createElement('p');
  taskDescription.classList.add('para-1');
  const addInput = document.querySelector('input');
  taskDescription.innerText = addInput.value;
  return taskDescription;
}

function createTaskDeleteBtn(event) {
  const deletebtn = document.createElement('button');
  deletebtn.setAttribute('class', 'btn-icon');
  deletebtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>';
  deletebtn.style.cssText = "color: red; font-size: 1.5em; border: none; outline: none; padding-inline: 2rem; cursor: pointer;";
  deletebtn.addEventListener('click', deleteAction);
  return deletebtn;
}

function deleteAction(event) {
  event.target.closest('.task-added').remove();
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input typ="text" />
<button class="btn-blue">Add Task</button>
<div class="main-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `taskPanel` will be the *last* created task panel by the time the click handler executes, and so `taskPanel.remove()` will remove that one only. The next time you click a delete button, that `taskPanel` element is no longer an element that is part of the HTML document, so nothing happens.

Taking a step back, you would not have had this problem if you had avoided another pattern that is not advised: avoid global variables when they get reassigned. Instead *return* what a function performs, and *pass* it what it needs:

```js
// Task list section
const taskBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-blue');
const addTask = document.querySelector('.main-content');

// Event Listeners
taskBtn.addEventListener('click', addPanel);

function addPanel(event) {
  // taskPanel is a local variable
  const taskPanel = createDiv();
  // pass it as argument
  createPara(taskPanel);
  // ... and again. Get the button reference for this taks panel
  const deletebtn = createBtn(taskPanel);
  removeContent(taskPanel, deletebtn); // pass both elements
};

function createDiv() { // There is no event passed: omit parameter
  // taskPanel is a local variable
  const taskPanel = document.createElement('ul');
  taskPanel.setAttribute('class', 'task-added');
  // Don't set css styles directly. Use CSS classes
  addTask.appendChild(taskPanel);
  return taskPanel;
}

//Create Paragraph
function createPara(taskPanel) { // argument determines where to create it
  const taskPara = document.createElement('li'); // local var
  taskPara.classList.add('para-1');
  const addInput = document.querySelector('input');
  taskPara.innerText = addInput.value;
  taskPanel.appendChild(taskPara);
}

//Create Button
function createBtn(taskPanel) {
  const deletebtn = document.createElement('button');
  deletebtn.setAttribute('class', 'btn-icon');
  deletebtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>';
  // don't set css styles here. Apply style to CSS class
  taskPanel.appendChild(deletebtn);
  return deletebtn; // return it so caller can attach handler
}

function removeContent(taskPanel, deletebtn) { // arguments
  deletebtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    taskPanel.remove(); // Now taskPanel is the one of the argument!
  });
}
```

```css
.btn-icon  {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding-inline: 2rem; 
  cursor: pointer;
}
.task-added {
  display: flex; 
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-block: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" />
<input><button class="btn-blue">Add</button>
<div class="main-content"></div>
```